# How to solve "fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory" on Windows when I trying to compile generated Cython C code

Tags: python, gcc, g++, cython, cythonize

I'm trying to make `.exe` file from my `main.py` file wih cython that will work fine on another machine without any other files.

First I did was to convert main.py code to C.
I did that with command in cmd `cython -3 main.py --embed`

Then as I understood I need to compile C generated code with some compiler.
I have installed gcc comiler and tried to compile my C code with this command:

```
gcc main.c -ID:\Programs\Python 10\include -LD:\Programs\Python 10\libs -lpython310  -fPIC -D MS_WIN64 -o Program.exe
```

But I'm getting this error all the time:

```
main.c:6:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
    6 | #include "Python.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I'm using Windows, tried to find the file `Python.h` in the include folder and it is there.
Might someone knows how to fix this problem? I can't find something helpful in the internet about this.

Comment: you probably just need to quote the include and lib paths

Comment: like this? `gcc main.c -I"D:\Programs\Python 10\include" -L"D:\Programs\Python 10\libs" -l"python310"  -fPIC -D MS_WIN64 -o Program.exe`

Comment: Yes - otherwise the spaces confuse it

Comment: Yes, it helped, but errors appeared in the code. Thanks for help!

Comment: might you know what to do with this trouble?  `d:/programs/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: d:/programs/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `WinMain'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`